# update entity using java script and symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony, doctrine-orm

I ask if there are any way to update an entity using javascript and symfony2.
when clicking on a button, a function in javascript should be called to update the entity in database 
I use symfony 2.6

Comment: Just send request to controller via ajax, no magic there.

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Ajax`. Javascript code sends a request (POST/GET/PUT) to an URL (Managed by Symfony), which can answer.

Communication between Javascript and Server is generally done using POST, and data sent back is generally done in XML/HTML or JSON.

There are plenty of tutorial and documentation, for example:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You can also look at `REST`, that defines common API on the Server side. There is a module that helps defining this interface with Symfony:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html